# Not able to find out height of a binary tree

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

I am not able to get the correct answer.

```
int height(Node* root) {
        // Write your code here.
       if (root == NULL)
         return 0;

      // find the height of each subtree
      int lh = height(root->left);
      int rh = height(root->right);

      return  max(lh,rh)+1;
}
```

Comment: Can you  give a specific example that fails and tell us what you expect?

Comment: Your logic looks right, but perhaps you have a C specific error which I am not seeing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you r solving the question where root is considered at a height 0.Here is the solution for newer one.

```
int height(Node* root) {
    if (root == NULL) return 0;
   if (root ->left== NULL && root->right== NULL)
     return 0;

  // find the height of each subtree
  int lh = height(root->left);
  int rh = height(root->right);

  return  max(lh,rh)+1;

    // Write your code here.
}
```